# React native PJSIP error in installation module

Tags: react-native, npm-install, sip, voip, pjsip

I try to install module PJSIP in my react-native project.

URL : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pjsip

but I am getting below error.

```
> react-native-pjsip@2.8.0 postinstall /Users/saty/react-native-pjsip
> bash libs.sh

npm WARN react-native-linear-gradient@2.5.6 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.55 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dom@15.6.2 requires a peer of react@^15.6.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 23
npm ERR! react-native-pjsip@2.8.0 postinstall: `bash libs.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 23
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-native-pjsip@2.8.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: add your package.json for reference

Comment: @KacperWiszczuk I am working on the macOS

Comment: @RizwanAhmedShivalli https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @RizwanAhmedShivalli - Did you find anything for above issue?

Answer (score 3):

Error 23 is usually a network issue. If you take a look at the script it tries to download the package 2.8.0 from here https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip-builder/releases/download/v2.8.0/release.tar.gz. You should confirm that you can download the release, or contact the owner, create an issue or use another module.

Or you could download it and install it manually.

Edit: This is also a bash script so if you are running this in Windows I dont see that script running there.

Comment: I am running on the macos, but bash script is not working.

Comment: I want the solution for the working script. I shared package.json in the comment as well.